# Aggregating positive values on multiple columns with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do aggregation functions on a specific database table with multiple columns.
For example:

`Sample Table 
   ID  Column1  Column2  Column3
   1      3        5        -2
   2     -1        4         6
   3      2       -1         3`

In this example, if I would like to sum the values in the 3 columns, I want to get the following result:
Column1: (3+2)=5, Column2(5+4)=9 and Column3(6+3)=9.
Thus, my question is whether this is possible with a single SQL query or I would have to go through creating temporary tables?

Note: The data set is big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to SUM the positive values, and ignore the negatives? If so try:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column1 > 0 THEN Column1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Column1PosTotal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column2 > 0 THEN Column2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Column2PosTotal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column3 > 0 THEN Column3 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Column3PosTotal'
FROM Table
```